What does "she" in "she needs" refer to?
Quill had breakfast with his grand-pa, who was busy reading a
"The St. Charles Post" article:

Quill: I mean, if she needs help mowing her lawn, I'll do it, but I
kinda feel like her son should help. He's gonna sit on the porch and
watch me do it. Like, he's a 45-year-old man, able-bodied, and I'm
mowing his lawn. It just feels weird.
Grand-pa: Don't get me started.
Quill: Oh, really? Now I kind of want to know.

What does "she" in "she needs" refer to?

Peter's stepgrandmother, the wife of Jason Quill, who lives in the house with Jason. "He" was presumably Peter Quill's uncle (Meredith's brother).
